# How to model this cURL call with the HttpClient?

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin, httpclient

How can I replicate this cURL request with the HttpClient class in C#?

```
curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ****" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ****" \
-G \
--data-urlencode "where={\"Usuario\":\"Luis\"}" \
https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/Usuarios
```

Comment: Please fully explain your question.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Response code is 201 (Created):

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id", "****");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "****");
    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/Usuarios", new StringContent("{\"Usuario\":\"Luis\"}"));    
}
```

Also I wouldn't share my API-key if I were you.

Comment: @Luis.f you can not send a payload in a Get method with HttpClient: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync(v=vs.118).aspx